# Local network ARP requests from Android app

Tags: android

I'm working on an app interacting with Network Enabled devices on a local network.

I'm currently working with IP addresses. However, on the long run, IP addresses will eventually change, breaking the connection. I'd like to store MAC addresses instead, and init my app by sending ARP requests and fetching the matching IP address for each stored MAC.

Is this the correct way to do this?

If so, which library should I use for such a task, and do any of you have a code example?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you can run code on the devices, consider giving them MDNS names and run an MDNS responder on each.  And then you'll probably want to give them each *unique* SSL certificates (tracing back to a root cert shipped in your app) against those names, too.

Answer (score -1):

You will probably need to access low-level components which Android & Java don't allow you to. Maybe with a rooted device ?

Comment: No need to root device, you can write c code with JNI to access lower level components